# Improving Datastore Query performance

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I use [Restlet](http://restlet.com/) for my application Rest framework and [Twist](https://github.com/textquo/twist) for Object mapping framework for GAE.

I installed [Appstats](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats) servlet and filter to monitor my application performance when deployed live.

Here are the results for querying a set of "posts" as the app is loaded:

```
datastore_v3.RunQuery   121ms
RPC Total   121ms
Grand Total 1110ms
```

From my interpretation of this, it looks to be that the Object mapping and datastore query is quite fast or is fine. My concern is why the **Grand Total is 1110ms**, how is that? What is the thing that consumed 989 ms?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to use Cloud Trace? https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-trace

Comment: Whatever you are doing with the result of your query is probably taking the rest of the time. How big is the data you are receiving from datastore and what are you doing with it before transmitting it to the requester? Is there anything else you are doing in your code after receiving the datastore result?

Comment: Could you also enable traces at the Restlet framework itself? So we could see where the time is spent...

Comment: we need to know what your code is doing, as others are pointing out. If the datastore returns in 121, and it takes you an extra 989 ms... what is your servlet doing besides the ".get()"?

Comment: @thierrytemplier How can I enable tracing in Restlet?